# Java timestamp, can not get correct value

Tags: java, mysql, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I want to convert this `1416990366` timestamp to date. here is how I do:

```
    Timestamp stamp = new Timestamp(1416990366);
    System.out.println("TimeStamp: " + stamp.toString());
    Date mDate = new Date(stamp.getTime());
```

but I get `Sat Jan 17 13:06:30 GMT+03:30 1970` while it must be `Wed, 26 Nov 2014 08:26:06 GMT` what is wrong?

**Edit:**

I get this value from server and I think they cut off miliseconds so i have to multiply it by 1000 but I get nothing, and again the wrong value. 
why this still dose not work `Timestamp stamp = new Timestamp(1000 * mIssue.getReleaseTime());` where `mIssue.getReleaseTime() = 1416990366`
can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The time specified to the `Timestamp` constructor is the time in milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT. `1416990366` evaluates to around 16 days from that epoch, hence the output that you're getting.

If you want the current time, you can pass `System.currentTimeMillis()` to the constructor.

**EDIT:**
Since the time that is obtained from the server is in milliseconds, you can multiply by 1000 and convert to `long` as follows:

```
Timestamp stamp = new Timestamp((long) 1000 * mIssue.getReleaseTime());
```

Comment: Thanks for helping, I get this value from server and I think they cut off miliseconds so i have to multiply it by 1000 but I get nothing, and again the wrong value.

Comment: why this still dose not work `Timestamp stamp = new Timestamp(1000 * mIssue.getReleaseTime());` where `mIssue.getReleaseTime() = 1416990366`

Comment: If this solves anything `System.out.println(new Date(0));` prints Thu Jan 01 **02:00:00** EET 1970!

Comment: @mmlooloo You would need to convert the result to `long`. Answer updated.

Answer (score 1):

## java.time

The modern way is with java.time classes.

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochSecond( 1416990366L );
```

Call `toString` to generate a String that represents its date-time value in standard ISO 8601 format.

> 2014-11-26T08:26:06Z

An [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) is a moment on the timeline in UTC with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond).

Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to [Android](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system)) in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (see [*How to use…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706)).

Comment: @mmlooloo See the last paragraph I added for ThreeTenABP project.

Comment: Thank you for introducing new library but actually in my case adding a new library also adds method counts and increases binary size of my apk, so still I prefer use old coding style unless I need a heavy time APIs . Again thanks :-)